# How to enable async supported for a spring MVC application in java configuration file (Not XML)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I know how to enable async support in a XML configuration, I have done so for filters and servlets by adding tag

```
async-supported>true/async-supported
```

How to do it in a Java config file. I create a WebInit class which implements WebApplicationInitializer and overrides onStartUp -what should I do next?

```
public class WebInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
      //What to do here, to move from XML to java config
 }
}
```

Comment: The javadoc has an example: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html. You need to register a configuration class for your Spring application, and this configuration class just needs to be annotated with `@EnabledAsync`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along the following lines -

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addServlet(servletName, myServlet);
registration.setAsyncSupported(true);
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry, did not realize that you were looking for a Spring specific solution. With Spring MVC you would just extend a [`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html) assuming that your root and web contexts are `@Configuration` based. This initializer in-turn extends from [AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.html), this class has asyncSupported flag set by default.

Comment: Biju, Thanks for the pointer, but I want to add this support to Spring Dispatcher servlet. I have used enableMvc and other annotations to configure MVC and there is no explicit mapping for spring dispatcher servlet. How can I retrieve the reference of created dispatcher servlet and add asyn supported tag to it?

Comment: Got it, I thought this is a generic question on how to set `async` flag for a servlet - edited my answer now for Spring specific servlet. See if the edit helps.